# Expression-Tree for array property

Tags: c#, arrays, expression-trees

Suppose we have this class

```
class ClassA
{
    public ClassB[] MyProperty { get; set; }
}
class ClassB
{
    public int[] AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to access the value for `AnotherProperty` for a given instance of `ClassA` and an array of indexes that reflect the two arrays So `{ 3 , 5 }` e.g. means the fourth element within the top-level (evaluates to `MyProperty`) and the sixth element within second level (`AnotherProperty`). Thus I´m going to create a `Func<ClassA, int[], int>` by the means of an expression-tree:

```
var instanceArgument = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass), "x");
var indexesArgument = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int[]), "i");

var expr = instanceArgument;
expr = Expression.Property(expr, "MyProperty");
expr = Expression.ArrayIndex(expr, ???);
expr = Expression.Property(expr, "AnotherProperty");
expr = Expression.ArrayIndex(expr, ???);
var f = Expression.Lambda<Func<ClassA, int[], int>>(expr, instanceArgument, indexesArgument);
```

As you can see I´m unsure on how to provide the indexes to the expression. I know I have to use the `indexesArgument` which reflects the indexes passed to our delegate, but how to access the values `3` and `5`?

Comment: If you want a function to take exactly two integers, you should have it accept two integers, not an array that you hope will be exactly of size two.  Additionally, since nothing about this is dynamic, you can just use a lambda to construct the expression.

Comment: Well, the tree is bit more dynamic as the properties to be accessed come from a string, something like `MyProperty[3].AnotherProperty[5]`. From this string I extract the names of the attributes and the indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a further `ArrayIndexExpression` to access the i-th element within our `indexes`-argument:

```
expr = Expression.Property(expr, "MyProperty");
expr = Expression.ArrayIndex(expr, Expression.ArrayIndex(indexesArgument, Exression.Constant(0));
expr = Expression.Property(expr, "AnotherProperty");
expr = Expression.ArrayIndex(expr, Expression.ArrayExpression(indexesArgument, Expression.Constant(1));
```

The `Expression.Constant(0)` leads to an `ArrayIndexExpression` of the first element within `indexes`, `Expression.Constant(1)` to the second one accordingly.

Now after having compiled the expression-tree we can call the delegate to access the second int-value for `AnotherProperty` of the first instance within `MyProperty`:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA 
{ 
    MyProperty = new[] { new ClassB 
    { 
        AnotherProperty = new[] { 1, 4 }
    }
};
int result = f(x, new[] { 0, 1 });
```

Comment: I think that's quite obvious from the fact that you are building expression like `(x, indexes) => x.MyProperty[indexes[0]].AnotherProperty[indexes[1]]` (it's easy to see the double array indexing and constants)

Comment: @IvanStoev Sure, *now* it is obvious to me. However if you aren´t that familiar with expression-trees as I, it´s not neccessarily obvious. Anyway nearly *every* question on SO is obvious to someone except the OP.

Comment: Hehe, sure. But the good thing with expressions is that you can always create compile time expression and examine it with the debugger to see what is in there :)

Comment: @IvanStoev While I appreciate your upvote you shouldn´t do so only because it was downvoted before. You should however do so because of the quality of the question and/or answer - which I hopefully achieved.

Comment: Not at problem at all. Regardless of my comments, I don't think the question and answer deserve downvotes. Cheers.